# Getting 401 Error When Using CSOM

Tags: csom, error, sharepoint-on-prem

I am attempting to connect to SharePoint 2016 Server (On Premise) using CSOM. I've researched a number of items and have found no solution. Here's the code I'm using:

```
clientCtx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            clientCtx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName","password");            
            //Get the Web
            var cliWeb = clientCtx.Web;
            //Get all of the lists
            var allLists = cliWeb.Lists;
            //Now package the query
            clientCtx.Load(allLists);
            //Now execute the query
            try
            {
                clientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

I can see from the ULS log the auth-N works as expected but that the account does not have any permissions. I'm signed in with a Site Collection admin account

> Successfully got user key for user. UserNameSuffix: '0#.w|XXXXXXXXX'. a9d0fc9e-de99-707e-8b46-5c178ad55341
>   08/22/2019 14:46:31.15  w3wp.exe (0x4584)                           0x1C94  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  a9d0fc9e-de99-707e-8b46-5c178ad55341
>   08/22/2019 14:46:31.16  w3wp.exe (0x4584)                           0x1C94  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8xfr    Medium      PermissionMask check failed for {75A3160C-BF3B-4D51-AAEF-2AC9D7437BC0}. Asking for 0x08000000, have 0x00000000  a9d0fc9e-de99-707e-8b46-5c178ad55341
>   08/22/2019 14:46:31.16  w3wp.exe (0x4584)                           0x1C94  SharePoint Foundation           Site Cache                      az4z8   Medium      Looking up SPSite by ID 2b98c19f-32f4-4498-a61c-bc8f6735119a in memory. a9d0fc9e-de99-707e-8b46-5c178ad55341
>   08/22/2019 14:46:31.16  w3wp.exe (0x4584)                           0x1C94  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8xfr    Medium      PermissionMask check failed for {75A3160C-BF3B-4D51-AAEF-2AC9D7437BC0}. Asking for 0x00010000, have 0x00000000  a9d0fc9e-de99-707e-8b46-5c178ad55341

Any insight as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the error message still the same if you change your code a) use domain in credentials (new NetworkCredential(domain\UserName, password);  b)  load Web and not AllLists ? (Web web = clientctx.Web; clientctx.Load(web);)

Comment: Thank you Celophysis, I did try the configuration using the syntax for the NetworkCredential constructor with domain\user, password. I also tried the constructor "user","password","domain" and all resulted in a 401 error. I did attempt to load just the web as you suggested and it also generates a 401 error. I suspect there is a configuration on the SharePoint server that I'm missing since the account is not getting anything assigned to the permission mask.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected the issue, the DNS was routing to the wrong site so the accounts did not have permission. Once that issue was corrected the code above worked as expected.